# How can I insert my data into this column and how would I update it?

Tags: mysql

Once again I would like to ask if anyone could help me on how would I insert and update it into my field column, this is bothering me for quite a while now.

the table looks like this;

```
----------------------------------------
id  | type | multiplier | rdMultiplier |
----------------------------------------
1   |  Reg  |  null     |    null      |
2   |  Spec |  null     |    null      |
3   |  DReg |  null     |    null      |
4   |  DSpec|  null     |    null      |
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to insert and update the 3rd and the 4th field.

Here is my code for getting the values coming from different textboxes:

```
$regularmul =  $this->input->get('regularmulti');
$specialmul =  $this->input->get('specialmulti');
$doubleregmul =  $this->input->get('doubleregmulti');
$doublespecmul =  $this->input->get('doublespecialmul');
$rd1 =  $this->input->get('restmul1');
$rd2 =  $this->input->get('restmul2');
$rd3 =  $this->input->get('restmul3');
$rd4 =  $this->input->get('restmul4');
```

Thank you for your patience in helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert data

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(fieldname1,fieldname2,fieldname3,fieldname4) VALUES ('$variablename1','$variablename2','$variablename3','$variablename4');
```

update data

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET fieldname1='$variablename1',fieldname2='$variablename2',fieldname3='$variablename3',fieldname4='$variablename4' WHERE field_id = 'so_and_so_id';
```